# How can I get the base url in an ActionMailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I want to send out an email with a deep link back into my app, but I'd rather not have to hard-code the URL or else I have to switch it when I move from one environment to the next. How can I obtain the base url of a web app from within an ActionMailer? For example, I'd love to be able to have something like:

```
<%= base_uri %>listCreate?first=foo&second=bar
```

render something like the following in my testing environment:

```
http://localhost:30000/myApp/listCreate?first=foo&second=bar
```

and the following in production:

```
http://www.myDomain.com/myApp/listCreate?first=foo&second=bar
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the defult url option in `config/environments/production.rb`

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'your.app.com' }
```

and in mail template

the link should be

```
<%= link_to 'myapp', myapp_list_url %>
```

Hope this could help

You can refer the Action Mailer [doc](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#generating-urls-in-action-mailer-views)

Comment: Thank you. This seems to have given me what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the default_url_options for your mailer in the controller where you have the current host for the request.

In my case, I send an email when I receive information in some lead creation form, so I have a LeadMailer. My solution was to create a before filter to set the host in the mailer.

Of course, you don't need to do it in a before filter, you could set it in your action.

My solutions looked like this:

```
class LeadsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_host, on: [:create]

  def set_host
    LeadsMailer.default_url_options = { host: request.host_with_port }
    LeadsMailer.asset_host = request.protocol + request.host_with_port
  end
end
```

I set the asset_host config because I wanted to use my images from the assets pipeline.

Now you can use the _url helpers as usual

```
<%= link_to 'something', something_url %>
```

Or your asset helpers

```
<%= image_url('logo.png')%>
```

Comment: That didn't quite work for me, the base url wasn't automatically added to the link_to URL. But! I could reference `SomeMailer.default_url_options[:host]` in my mailer view after setting it in my controller. Thanks!

Comment: @MikeBethany Which Rails version are you working with? Maybe in newer Rails versions it requires some corrections

Comment: I'm using Rails 4.2.3